# Undefined method `selected' for #<UIButton:0xa7f1390>

Tags: ios, iphone, ruby, rubymotion

I am using RubyMotion to create a toggle button using UIButton.

This is what I'm doing

```
@favorite = rmq.append(UIButton, data[:fav] == 1? :fav_button_selected : :fav_button_deselected).get
@favorite.setTitle("d", forState: UIControlStateNormal)
@favorite.setTitle("s", forState: UIControlStateSelected)


@favorite.on(:touch) do |sender|
  sender.selected = !sender.selected #gives error
  # sender.selected = true ##This works fine!
end
```

However, I get an error that

```
`block in update:': undefined method `selected' for #<UIButton:0xa7f8f80> (NoMethodError)
    from uicontrol.rb:93:in `call:event:'
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. I can set the `selected` property fine but when I try to get it I get the above error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you want to express with `!sender.selected`? I don't get this.

Comment: I want to express a toggle button. When its clicked I want to change the selected property to the opposite. As mentioned in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884850/undefined-method-selected-for-uibutton0xa7f1390

Comment: Of course. Now I get it.

Comment: Any chance that you cannot set the selection state via `selected` but something like `select`?

Comment: for now what is working for me is setting it with `selected` but fetching it by `isSelected` not sure why there is a difference though.

Answer (score 1):

easy!  and you don't need to use `isSelected`

```
sender.selected?  # <= add the '?' mark :-)
```

Comment: you CAN use `isSelected`, that's the same method, but RubyMotion provides the more idiomatic `selected?` method.  any "getter" that has the pattern "isSomethingBlaFoo" will have a method `somethingBlaFoo?`